# Pattern matching to create a new column in sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Looking for some guidance on where to start with a project that likely uses pattern matching in some form. Currently I have a table with a column of property identification numbers that resembles below:

```
PropertyID|   Property Name|  

A001          Jefferson
A002          Madison
A002-01       Madison Outhouse
A002-02       James Madison Statue
A003          Franklin
A004          Jackson
A004-field2   Jackson Fields
...           ...
A2001         Tubman
```

The PropertyID field is the primary key for the dataset. The string before the hyphen represents a parent property, while the values after the hyphen indicate sub-properties associated with the parent. What I'm attempting to create is a new column called "Parent Property Name" That would look like below:

```
PropertyID|   Property Name|          | Parent Property Name|

A001          Jefferson                 Jefferson
A002          Madison                   Madison
A002-01       Madison Outhouse          Madison
A002-02       James Madison Statue      Madison
A003          Franklin                  Franklin
A004          Jackson                   Jackson
A004-field2   Jackson Fields            Jackson
...           ...
A2001         Tubman                    Tubman
```

Basically what I'm trying to accomplish is if the string is unique before the hyphen/does not have a hyphen return "Property Name" as "Parent Property Name", If there is a hyphen return the "Property Name" value of of the parent (i.e. matching PropertyID before hyphen that does not contain a hyphen itself.

Any thoughts on how I should approach this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: use a recursive cte, taking those without hyphens are the root, and those with as the recursive items... sql fiddle coming up...

Comment: ps. How deep does your hierarchy go; i.e. here you've just shown one level; but could you have a parent-of-a-parent-of-an-item?

Comment: Can you start again or is this process embedded?

I would have one table for the "parent property" and an additional table for the "sub properties" and link them with primary/foreign key constraints

Comment: Jon, it's embedded, unfortunately. I agree that what you suggest is a far better design.There is a column called "sub-property" that is a 1/0 value though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do this using a `join`: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/e426c5/12)

```
select t.*, tparent.PropertyId
from t join
     t tparent
     on left(t.PropertyId, charindex('-', t.PropertyId + '-') - 1) = tparent.PropertyId;
```

You can also use `first_value()`: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/e426c5/13)

```
select t.*,
       first_value(propertyId) over (partition by left(t.PropertyId, charindex('-', t.PropertyId + '-') - 1)
                                     order by PropertyId) as parent_propertyid
from t;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `subquery` :

```
select *,
   (case when charindex ('-', ltrim(rtrim(PropertyID))) > 0
         then (select top 1 t1.PropertyName 
               from table t1
               where t1.PropertyID = left(t.PropertyId, charindex('-', t.PropertyId + '-') - 1)
              ) else PropertyName
     end) as  [Parent Property Name]
from table t;
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you're after: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/e426c5/3)

```
with CTE as 
(
  select PropertyId
  , PropertyName
  , PropertyId ParentId
  , PropertyName ParentName
  , PropertyId AncestorId
  , PropertyName AncestorName
  from Property
  where PropertyId not like '%-%'

  union all

  select b.PropertyId
  , b.PropertyName
  , a.PropertyId ParentId
  , a.PropertyName ParentName
  , a.AncestorId
  , a.AncestorName
  from CTE a
  inner join Property b
  on b.PropertyId like a.PropertyId + '-%'
  and b.PropertyId not like a.PropertyId + '-%-%' --avoid having grandchildren too soon

)
select * 
from CTE 
order by PropertyId
```

The first block of code gets all root elements; i.e. those without hyphens.  These values are their own parents & ancestors.  These are also the only values that will appear as ancestors of other results, since they're at the top level.

```
select PropertyId
, PropertyName
, PropertyId ParentId
, PropertyName ParentName
, PropertyId AncestorId
, PropertyName AncestorName
from Property
where PropertyId not like '%-%'
```

We then use the recursive bit to capture the child elements.  This takes those elements from the table whose PropertyId is the same as the table's existing records' PropertyId, only with a hyphen and a new value on the end.  We exclude those which have a second hyphen (or more) after this, to ensure we don't list a great grandchild as a child.

In this same block, we assign the values differently; rather than Property, Parent, and Ancestor receiving the same values, Property is the current property, Parent is the PropertyId of the parent record, and Ancestor is the Parent record's Ancestor.

```
  select b.PropertyId
  , b.PropertyName
  , a.PropertyId ParentId
  , a.PropertyName ParentName
  , a.AncestorId
  , a.AncestorName
  from CTE a
  inner join Property b
  on b.PropertyId like a.PropertyId + '-%'
  and b.PropertyId not like a.PropertyId + '-%-%'
```

---

### Note

I wondered if my use of `LIKE` was appropriate, or if alternatives such as `CHARINDEX` may perform better.   In investigating I found [this post](http://cc.davelozinski.com/sql/like-vs-substring-vs-leftright-vs-charindex) which shows that CharIndex is best, but per the comments others have found different results, and running this myself I also saw inconsistent behaviours on different machines.  So I suspect this is a scenario prone to premature optimisation; i.e. make sure what's there works; then if you need to optimise it test those optimisations out on the environment this code will be run on to ensure the stats are relevant.

That said, here's a version using `CHARINDEX`, should you wish to test / compare.  This is based on [@GordonLinoff](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50627876/361842)'s solution.  [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/e426c5/19)

```
with CTE as 
(
  select PropertyId
  , PropertyName
  , PropertyId ParentId
  , PropertyName ParentName
  , PropertyId AncestorId
  , PropertyName AncestorName
  , 0 LastHyphenCharIndex
  from Property
  where charindex('-', PropertyId) = 0

  union all

  select b.PropertyId
  , b.PropertyName
  , a.PropertyId 
  , a.PropertyName 
  , a.AncestorId
  , a.AncestorName
  , charindex('-',b.PropertyId, a.LastHyphenCharIndex)
  from CTE a
  inner join Property b
  --on left(b.PropertyId, charindex('-',b.PropertyId, a.LastHyphenCharIndex)) = a.PropertyId + '-'
  on left(b.PropertyId, nullif(charindex('-',b.PropertyId, a.LastHyphenCharIndex),0)-1) = a.PropertyId 

)
select * 
from CTE 
order by PropertyId
```

Comment: I really appreciate the time and effort. I'm very new to cte's (and, I suppose, sql in general), but this looks like it's the trick. I'm going to do some testing on the actual data (thousands of properties and I'm sure there are some naming/numbering quirks in there somewhere) and come back and mark as answered. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by a JOIN as follows:
We are extracting the Substring part of the PropertyID before the "-" symbol and joining back to the same table with this. IF a record does not have "-" symbol, induce one so the substring part always returns something and also the CHARINDEX() -1 part does not return a negative value to the SUBSTRING function for length argument.

```
DECLARE @Temp AS TABLE ( PropertyID NVARCHAR(MAX), PropertyName NVARCHAR(MAX))
INSERT INTO @Temp ( PropertyID ,
                    PropertyName )


SELECT 'A001',          'Jefferson'              UNION ALL
SELECT 'A002',          'Madison'                UNION ALL
SELECT 'A002-01',       'Madison Outhouse'       UNION ALL
SELECT 'A002-02',       'James Madison Statue'   UNION ALL
SELECT 'A003',          'Franklin'               UNION ALL
SELECT 'A004',          'Jackson'                UNION ALL
SELECT 'A004-field2',   'Jackson Fields'         UNION ALL
SELECT 'A2001',         'Tubman'                 


    SELECT *, CHARINDEX('-',T1.PropertyID)
FROM @Temp T1 LEFT JOIN @Temp T2 
ON SUBSTRING(T1.PropertyID,1,CHARINDEX('-',T1.PropertyID+'-')-1) =  T2.PropertyID
```